# Reaching layout elements and threads from within a callback

Tags: android, jsch

I am uploading using `JSch` with

```
sftp.put(filename, target,progressMonitor());
```

with `progressMonitor` as seen below. The problem is that I cannot access the `progress bar` in `layout` and I also cannot do a `runOnUiThread`, as `findViewById` and `runOnUiThread` are not being found. How do I reach `runOnUiThread` and the `progress bar` from within `pbF`?

EDIT: I tried

```
private Context c;
```

and

```
public progressMonitor(Context c) {
    this.c = c;
}
```

but I still cannot access `findViewById` using `c.findViewById` and `pbFortschritt2` using `c.pbFortschritt2`

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpProgressMonitor;

public class progressMonitor implements SftpProgressMonitor{
    private long max                = 0;
    private long count              = 0;
    private long percent            = 0;

    // If you need send something to the constructor, change this method
    public progressMonitor() {}

    public void init(int op, java.lang.String src, java.lang.String dest, long max) {
        this.max = max;
        Log.d("sdf","starting");
        Log.d("sdf",""+src); // Origin destination
        Log.d("sdf",""+dest); // Destination path
        Log.d("sdf",""+max); // Total filesize
    }

    public void pbF(long prozent)
    {
        ProgressBar pbFortschritt2 = (ProgressBar)MainActivity.this.findViewById();
        pbFortschritt2.progress = progress.toInt()
    }


    public boolean count(long bytes){
        this.count += bytes;
        long percentNow = this.count*100/max;
        if(percentNow>this.percent){
            this.percent = percentNow;
            Log.d("sdf","progress "+this.percent); // Progress 0,0
            Log.d("sdf",""+max); //Total ilesize
            Log.d("sdf",""+this.count); // Progress in bytes from the total
        }

        return(true);
    }

    public void end(){
        Log.d("sdf","finished");// The process is over
        Log.d("sdf",""+this.percent); // Progress
        Log.d("sdf",""+max); // Total filesize
        Log.d("sdf",""+this.count); // Process in bytes from the total
    }
}
```

EDIT: I solved it by passing the progress bar itself. Also it seemed that it ran on the ui anyways, so I didn't need `runOnUiThread`.

Answer (score 0):

I would you recommend you to send and broadcast message from your progressMonitor class. Then inside an Activity, you implement a listener to perform the action.

```
public class MainActivity() extends Activity {

    public static final String BROADCAST_INTENT = "BROADCAST_INTENT";
    public static final String ACTION = "action";
    public static final int HIDE_PROGRESSBAR = 1;


    private BroadcastReceiver pushNotificationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           int type = intent.getIntExtra(ACTION, -1);
           switch (type) {
               case HIDE_PROGRESSBAR:
                   // your hide progressbar logic
                   break;
               default:
                    break;
           }
       }
    };


    override fun onResume() {
       super.onResume()
       registerReceiver( notificationReceiver, IntentFilter(BROADCAST_INTENT))
    }


    override fun onPause() {
       super.onPause()
       unregisterReceiver(notificationReceiver)
    }


}
```

And like that, you send the broadcast:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.BROADCAST_INTENT);
i.putExtra(MainActivity.ACTION, MainActivity.HIDE_PROGRESSBAR);
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html

Comment: Seems a bit overkill

Comment: Not that much, and since you are in different threads, it's safer to communicate between them. I just added some code to exemplify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// First make an interface for progress update

public interface IProgressUpdateCBs {
    void progressupdate(int status);

}


// In your activity

// implement the interface
private static class ProgressUpdateCBs implements IProgressUpdateCBs {

    private WeakReference<YourActivity> mActivity;

    public ActivationValidationCBs(YourActivity activity) {
        mActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
    }

    private void updateUI(int status) {
        YourActivity activity = mActivity.get();
        if (activity != null) {
            // update UI here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void progressupdate(int status) {
        updateUI();

    }
}

 // Activity onCreate
 ProgressUpdateCBs cbs = new ProgressUpdateCBs(this);
 ProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new ProgressMonitor(cbs);


 // Form ProgressMonitor class
 private IProgressUpdateCBs mCbs;
 public progressMonitor(IProgressUpdateCBs cbs) {
    mCbs = cbs;
 }

 // when progress is updated call
 mCbs.progressupdate(status)
```